# How to offset instantiated GameObject to avoid overlap (numbers ex 1, 10, 100, 1000)?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
  string scoreText = score.ToString ();
    for (int i = 0; i < scoreText.Length; i++){ 
        var go = (GameObject)Instantiate(Resources.Load(scoreText[i].ToString()));
        go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, 0.08F, 0);
     }
```

I am instantiating GameObjects which are numbers. They represent the ever changing score. When my numbers are initiated I need them to have some space apart. This should be simple but I've been stuck with this. Can someone point out how this is done please?

I tried by adding space between characters to string scoreText but this just makes characters after the first character disappear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start from an initial position and use the for loop's iterator `i` to increase your position.

```
for (int i = 0; i < scoreText.Length; i++)
{
    ...
    go.transform.localPosition = new Vector3(0, i * 0.08F, 0);
}
```

That will start with 0 as the initial position and then add 0.08F for every new object.

```
0 * 0.08F = 0
1 * 0.08F = 0.08F
2 * 0.08F = 0.16F

etc.
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: This is simple, works perfectly, and I totally overlooked it and was not thinking the right way. Thank you!!